# Enumerating all edge-disjoint shortest paths from "s" to "t"

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

Given:

1. An edge-weighted directed graph $G$
2. A start vertex $s$
3. A target vertex $t$

I want to enumerate all edge-disjoint shortest paths from $s$ to $t$, in ascending order of path length.

So, as an example, given the following graph:

[image]

I want the algorithm to output the following paths in the following order:

1. A $\rightarrow$ B $\rightarrow$ C (length: 1+1)
2. A $\rightarrow$ C (length: 3)
3. A $\rightarrow$ B $\rightarrow$ C (length: 2+2)
4. A $\rightarrow$ C (length: 5)

The simplest algorithm I can imagine is as follows:

1. Apply shortest path-algorithm to $G$ (e.g. Dijkstra, or Bellman-Ford if $G$ has negative-weight edges) to find the shortest path from $s$ to $t$ (if no path exists then terminate)
2. Append this shortest path to the list of shortest paths
3. Remove all edges in this shortest path from the graph, to obtain a new graph, and apply step 1 to this new graph.

If we let $p$ denote the number of edge-disjoint shortest paths in $G$, then the complexity of this algorithm is simply $p$ times the complexity of whichever shortest path algorithm is chosen.

Is there a more efficient algorithm than this?